# Oracle Query grouping with condition

Tags: oracle

I have a query result like this:

```
DNAME           JOB       Total Empl    Average Sa
ACCOUNTING      CLERK           1       15600
ACCOUNTING      MANAGER         1       29400
ACCOUNTING      PRESIDENT       1       60000
ACCOUNTING      All Jobs        3       35000
RESEARCH        ANALYST         2       36000
RESEARCH        CLERK           2       11400
RESEARCH        MANAGER         1       35700
RESEARCH        All Jobs        5       26100
SALES           CLERK           1       11400
SALES           MANAGER         1       34200
SALES           SALESMAN        4       16800
SALES           All Jobs        6       18800
All Departments All Jobs        14      24878.5714
```

Is it possible to change become like this?

```
DNAME           JOB       Total Empl   Average Sa
ACCOUNTING      CLERK           1       15600
                MANAGER         1       29400
                PRESIDENT       1       60000
                All Jobs        3       35000
RESEARCH        ANALYST         2       36000
                CLERK           2       11400
                MANAGER         1       35700
                All Jobs        5       26100
SALES           CLERK           1       11400
                MANAGER         1       34200
                SALESMAN        4       16800
                All Jobs        6       18800
All Departments All Jobs        14      24878.5714
```

My existing query:

```
SELECT 
DECODE(GROUPING(dname), 1, 'All Departments', dname) AS dname,
DECODE(GROUPING(job), 1, 'All Jobs', job) AS job,
COUNT(*) "Total Empl", AVG(sal) * 12 "Average Sal"
FROM emp, dept
WHERE dept.deptno = emp.deptno
GROUP BY ROLLUP (dname, job);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to place your current query into a CTE, and then generate the department names only when it is the first record in the group:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        DECODE(GROUPING(d.dname), 1, 'All Departments', d.dname) AS dname,
        DECODE(GROUPING(job), 1, 'All Jobs', job) AS job,
        COUNT(*) "Total Empl",
        AVG(sal) * 12 "Average Sal",
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DECODE(GROUPING(d.dname), 1, 'All Departments', d.dname)
            ORDER BY DECODE(GROUPING(job), 1, 'All Jobs', job)) rn
    FROM emp e
    INNER JOIN dept d
        ON d.deptno = e.deptno
    GROUP BY ROLLUP (dname, job)
)

SELECT
    CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN dname ELSE '' END AS dname,
    job,
    "Total Empl",
    "Average Sal"
FROM cte
ORDER BY
    dname,
    job;
```

While this may meet your expectation, such presentation issues are usually best handled in the presentation layer, e.g. something like PHP.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your reply. I never though it will that hard to understand. I'm using analogy at previous post, and i changed to my real case. can you please give me another sample based on my real case? i edited the post. thanks

Comment: @user2236102 And I have rolled back your question to what you originally asked.  Please do _not_ radically change your question after users have already taken the time to give you an answer.

Comment: oh, i'm sorry i didn't mean to impolite. I just confuse

Comment: Well does my answer work?  If it does work, can you adapt it to your actual data?  If you _can't_ easily adapt it, then maybe you asked the wrong question.

Answer (score 0):

Front-end tools like SQL*Plus have specialized features to do exactly what you need.

In SQL*Plus, you simply need to issue the following command *before* you run the query AS IS:

```
break on dname
```

You can do the same in SQL Developer if you issue the same `BREAK` command on the worksheet (and you execute it), and then you execute the query "as a script" (the "Run Script" button or F5).

If for some reason you must do it all in a single SQL statement, here is one way. Notice the third line in the code - it is the last argument to DECODE. You are not seeing double - it is a second (nested) call to DECODE.

```
SELECT 
DECODE(GROUPING(dname), 1, 'All Departments', 
  decode(job, min(job) over (partition by dname), dname) -- instead of just dname
) AS dname,
DECODE(GROUPING(job), 1, 'All Jobs', job) AS job,
COUNT(*) "Total Empl", AVG(sal) * 12 "Average Sal"
FROM scott.emp, scott.dept
WHERE dept.deptno = emp.deptno
 10  GROUP BY ROLLUP (dname, job);

DNAME           JOB       Total Empl Average Sal
--------------- --------- ---------- -----------
ACCOUNTING      CLERK              1       15600
                MANAGER            1       29400
                PRESIDENT          1       60000
                All Jobs           3       35000
RESEARCH        ANALYST            2       36000
                CLERK              2       11400
                MANAGER            1       35700
                All Jobs           5       26100
SALES           CLERK              1       11400
                MANAGER            1       34200
                SALESMAN           4       16800
                All Jobs           6       18800
All Departments All Jobs          14  24878.5714
```